# Dockerfile RUN command result

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to process the results of a [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) command in Dockerfile? Specifically I would like to change what happents after this command depending on the result of the script it runs.

Comment: No, this is not possible and not intended (with the exception of failing the complete build as a kind-of "logic"). Dockerfiles are supposed to be *deterministic*, and having logic inside them might change the possible outcome. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

It is best to wrap up any complex command in a script.

Then you can execute that script

```
COPY myscript
RUN myscript
```

Said script can, when it is run, chain multiple commands and has access to their result.
As any regular shell script, it can run commands based on conditional statements.

Comment: I can do that. But said script must be the last command in a `Dockerfile` to show some status. Otherwise `docker build` will execute with no indication that the image wasn't built correctly.

Comment: @ilya1725 if the script returns a non-zero exit status, Dockerfile will fail, no? (as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/37143794/6309)

Comment: yes, it will. Perhaps I want more of `sh` functionality from Dockerfile that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @ilya1725 yes, but wrapping that in a script should be enough.